# Dos Box 0.74 not working in Windows 10 32 bit. Any Suggestions?

Tags: c, turbo-c, dosbox

I have installed Dos Box to run Turbo C in it. But it is not getting executed. I am just getting a black screen saying welcome to Dos box 0.74 and this:

```
Z:\>SET BLASTER=A220 I7 D1 H5 T6
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming and without further details, it's impossible to say where it *could* belong

Comment: Where should I ask these type of questions?

Comment: give more details on your question, I feel it COULD belong on e.g. superuser (or maybe you just don't know how to deal with the command prompt of DOS?) -- just clarify. If it's really about getting a piece of software to work, superuser might be the place.

Comment: You could try on superuser. But did you try setting the "compatibility mode" for _DosBox.exe_? Also if that's not enough you could try running it as Administrator (as it might require some additional privileges).

Comment: Does it say `Z:\\` again after that? Then it's working.

Comment: I tried setting the compatibility mode and running as administrator both didn't work @CristiFati

Comment: No Z again after that @AndrewMedico

Comment: First of all, for being a good question, it needs ALL the details. In case of problems with some software, a screenshot might help. And then, it would still be the wrong site. Inside stackexchange network, "superuser" would probably be the best match. There are some dedicated dosbox support forums at http://www.vogons.org/ but you'll probably get lectured there that "dosbox is for games, not for serious applications".

Comment: ok thanks for the suggestion @FelixPalmen. I will keep in mind next time.

Comment: @SaurabhArora: Stop Using Turbo C. It is useless compiler. Today is 2015. Read this to know why not to use Turbo C. Turbo C is an ancient & very old compiler that doesn't confirm to C standard. It still supports default to int rule for function return type which is banned by C99. Use gcc or clang compiler.